# Can we give two values in the input type of a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to give two values in a checkbox as on these two values the checkbox should be checked.

Can I use an if condition ? or anything else? I cant think of any good idea.

```
   <div class="Checkbox" style="width: 40px; height: 35px; margin-top: 3px;">
     <input type="checkbox" name="boxselector"  id="ROICheckBox"  onclick ="toggleCheckboxes(this);"   value="ROI" />
    <label for="ROICheckBox"  style="height: 10px; padding-bottom: 18px;" ></label>
   </div>
```

Now I have one more value **Pixel** which should use the same checkbox as **ROI** .
How can I do that ??

```
$("[name=boxselector]").click(function(
                      myPixelSetSel = undefined;
                       mySel = new Box2();
                       if (this.value === "ROI"){
                           mySel.isROI = true;
                       }
                       else if (this.value === "Layer"){
                           mySel.isLayer = true;
                       }
                       else if (this.value === "Metrics"){
                           mySel.isMetrics = true;
                          myPixelSetSel = 1;
//                           mySel = undefined;
                       }
                        else if (this.value === "MeasBox"){
                           mySel.isMeasBox = true;
                       }
                       else if(this.value === "Pixel"){
                         myPixelSetSel = 1;
                         mySel = undefined;
                    }

                } else {
                    sel = {};
                    mySel = undefined;
                    myPixelSetSel = undefined;
                }     
        });
       });
```

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense since the concept of a checkbox *value* is just that, a value. And the idea of it being two is confusing at best. I think what you are asking is instead how could you programmatically turn a checkbox on or off based on some business logic. That said it changes the questions context dramatically. Also since you've offered no JS code or example link (jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net) there isn't enough scope to the question to formulate a focused answer.

Comment: Not sure if I get exactly what you mean, but you can do `name='boxselector[ROI]'` and `name='boxselector[Pixel]'` in separate `input` elements, which allows both values to be passed when each is checked.

Comment: The checkbox element is probably the wrong element to use here. This element has two values - one when checked and another when unchecked. The unchecked element is not submitted to the server. If you are just changing the prompts then - give the label an id. In the script - if checked == false then get the id and put the appropriate text for the label.

Comment: My guess is that it would be better to do this server-side or in javascript (depending on what this form input is used for).  If Pixel should be equal to ROI, then some logic like `value_of_pixel_and_roi = boolean_for_boxselector_checkbox` should suffice.

Comment: there are two kinds of rectangles on my page which is selected when this checkbox is checked so I want two types of rectangles to be active when this single checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have an array of these two values when first one is checked and let's suppose is submitted for example:
Take a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/vcfvmLsy/

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  var arr = [];
  var chkel = $('input[name="boxselector"]');

  var valueToAdd = "Pixel";
  if ($(chkel).is(':checked')) {
    if ($(chkel).val() == "ROI")
      arr.push($(chkel).val());
    arr.push(valueToAdd);
  }
  console.log(arr);
  alert(arr[0]);
  alert(arr[1]);
  // Prevent actual submit for demo purposes:
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Checkbox" style="width: 40px; height: 35px; margin-top: 3px;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="boxselector" id="ROICheckBox" onclick="toggleCheckboxes(this);" value="ROI" checked="checked" />
  <label for="ROICheckBox" style="height: 10px; padding-bottom: 18px;"></label>
</div>
<form>
  <input id='my_match' type='hidden' name='my_match[]' />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```